# Mongoose nested models vs subdocuments (by performance)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to develop a new webapp (with MEAN stack). I have only developed a couple before.

I need to store devices (like 100k documents).
Each device will have +1 million readings. And each time I access the list of readings I will have to filter the content (by specific fields) and get like 1k records max.

I don't know what the design should be like, looking for best performace.

I have 3 options in mind:

---

**Option1, using subdocuments:**

```
var deviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    device_id: Number,
    serialNumber: String,
    readings:[{
        timestamp: Date,
        lat: Number,
        long: Number,
        otherfield1: String,
        ...
    }]
},{ timestamps: true, strict: false });
```

Note: I only access the DB once; I access the device and I have all the readings with me, but the document will be huge to handle.

---

**Option2, separate collections:**

```
var deviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    device_id: Number,
    serialNumber: String
},{ timestamps: true, strict: false });


var readingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    device_id: Number,
    timestamp: Date,
    lat: Number,
    long: Number,
    otherfield1: String,
    ...
},{ timestamps: true, strict: false });
```

Note: I access the DB twice; One to get the device and again to get the readings. I will filter the readings by the deviceid and by date, for example, but each document will be tiny.

---

**Option3, nested documents:**

```
var deviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    device_id: Number,
    serialNumber: String,
    readings: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Reading' }]
},{ timestamps: true, strict: false });


var readingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timestamp: Date,
    lat: Number,
    long: Number,
    otherfield1: String,
    ...
},{ timestamps: true, strict: false });
```

Note: I haven't use this option never. I would have to populate all the time and I don't know if this will give best performance:

```
Device.
  find(...).
  populate({
    path: 'readings',
    match: { timestamp: { $gte: xxxx}},
    select: 'lat long',
    options: { limit: 1000 }
  }).
  exec()
```

---

Which of the three has best performace?